# Comparison of two strings in Lua

Tags: string, lua, comparison, lua-table

I am trying to compare two strings where the first string is a single element of an array and the second array is just a regular string.  For some reason, the comparison is not coming through as true.  Hopefully, someone can point me in the right direction!

```
empty =  "        " 
pawn =   "  Pawn  " 
rook =   "  Rook  " 
knight = " Knight " 
bishop = " Bishop " 
queen =  "  Queen " 
king =   "  King  "

emptyspot = {} 
for i = 1, 8 do
    emptyspot[i] = {}
    for j = 1, 8 do
        emptyspot[i][j] = "    /    "   
    end 
end

function chessBoard() 
    io.write("\n\nWelcome to LuaChess!\n\n") 
    io.write("          1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8    \n") 
    io.write("      *************************************************************************\n") 
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("    A *".. emptyspot[1][1] ..
    "*"..emptyspot[1][2].."*"..emptyspot[1][3].."*"..emptyspot[1][4]..      
    "*"..emptyspot[1][5].."*"..emptyspot[1][6].."*"..emptyspot[1][7].."*"..emptyspot[1][8].."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("     *************************************************************************\n") 
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("    B *".. emptyspot[2][1] ..
    "*"..emptyspot[2][2].."*"..emptyspot[2][3].."*"..emptyspot[2][4]..      
    "*"..emptyspot[2][5].."*"..emptyspot[2][6].."*"..emptyspot[2][7].."*"..emptyspot[2][8].."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("     *************************************************************************\n") 
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("    C *".. emptyspot[3][1] ..
    "*"..emptyspot[3][2].."*"..emptyspot[3][3].."*"..emptyspot[3][4]..      
    "*"..emptyspot[3][5].."*"..emptyspot[3][6].."*"..emptyspot[3][7].."*"..emptyspot[3][8].."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("     *************************************************************************\n") io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("    D *".. emptyspot[4][1] ..
    "*"..emptyspot[4][2].."*"..emptyspot[4][3].."*"..emptyspot[4][4]..      
    "*"..emptyspot[4][5].."*"..emptyspot[4][6].."*"..emptyspot[4][7].."*"..emptyspot[4][8].."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("     *************************************************************************\n") io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("    E *".. emptyspot[5][1] ..
    "*"..emptyspot[5][2].."*"..emptyspot[5][3].."*"..emptyspot[5][4]..      
    "*"..emptyspot[5][5].."*"..emptyspot[5][6].."*"..emptyspot[5][7].."*"..emptyspot[5][8].."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("     *************************************************************************\n") io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("    F *".. emptyspot[6][1] ..
    "*"..emptyspot[6][2].."*"..emptyspot[6][3].."*"..emptyspot[6][4]..      
    "*"..emptyspot[6][5].."*"..emptyspot[6][6].."*"..emptyspot[6][7].."*"..emptyspot[6][8].."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("     *************************************************************************\n") io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("    G *".. emptyspot[7][1] ..
    "*"..emptyspot[7][2].."*"..emptyspot[7][3].."*"..emptyspot[7][4]..      
    "*"..emptyspot[7][5].."*"..emptyspot[7][6].."*"..emptyspot[7][7].."*"..emptyspot[7][8].."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("     *************************************************************************\n") io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("    H *".. emptyspot[8][1] ..
    "*"..emptyspot[8][2].."*"..emptyspot[8][3].."*"..emptyspot[8][4]..      
    "*"..emptyspot[8][5].."*"..emptyspot[8][6].."*"..emptyspot[8][7].."*"..emptyspot[8][8].."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("      *".. empty ..
    "*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*"..empty.."*\n")
    io.write("     *************************************************************************\n\n")

    io.write("      Choose a piece to move and the location\n      for it to be moved to separated by a space:\n") 
end

function initBoard()    
    emptyspot[1][1] = rook  
    emptyspot[1][2] = knight
    emptyspot[1][3] = bishop    
    emptyspot[1][4] = queen     
    emptyspot[1][5] = king  
    emptyspot[1][6] = bishop    
    emptyspot[1][7] = knight
    emptyspot[1][8] = rook  
    emptyspot[8][1] = rook  
    emptyspot[8][2] = knight    
    emptyspot[8][3] = bishop    
    emptyspot[8][4] = queen
    emptyspot[8][5] = king  
    emptyspot[8][6] = bishop    
    emptyspot[8][7] = knight    
    emptyspot[8][8] = rook  
    for i = 1, 8 do         
        emptyspot[2][i] = pawn  
    end     
    for i = 1, 8 do         
        emptyspot[7][i] = pawn  
    end
end

function swapPieces(piece1, piece2)     
    temp = piece1   
    piece1 = piece2
    piece2 = temp 
end

function movePawnPlayerOne(spot1, spot2)    
    spot1 = spot1 + 1
    emptyspot[spot1][spot2] = pawn  
    print(emptyspot[spot1][spot2]) 
end


initBoard() 
while true do   
    chessBoard()
    --Take first input for movement     
    input = io.read("*line")    
    loc1 = string.sub(input,1,1)
    loc2 = string.sub(input,2,2)

    if((loc1 == "A") or (loc1 == "a")) then         
        loc1 = 1        
    end     
    if ((loc1 == "B") or (loc1 == "b")) then        
        loc1 = 2        
    end     
    if ((loc1 == "C") or (loc1 == "c")) then        
        ioc1 = 3
    end     
    if ((loc1 == "D") or (loc1 == "d")) then        
        loc1 = 4        
    end     
    if ((loc1 == "E") or (loc1 == "e")) then
        loc1 = 5
    end     
    if ((loc1 == "F") or (loc1 == "f")) then        
        loc1 = 6
    end     
    if ((loc1 == "G") or (loc1 == "g")) then    
        loc1 = 7
    end     
    if ((loc1 == "H") or (loc1 == "h")) then        
        loc1 = 8
    end

    if (emptyspot[loc1][loc2] == pawn) then         
        movePawnPlayerOne(loc1, loc2)   
    end

    print(emptyspot[3][1])

    if string.find(input, "restart") then 
        initBoard()     
    end     
    if string.find (input, "exit") then 
        os.exit()   
    end 
end
```

The piece of code in question is towards the bottom.  Both `emptyspot[][]` and `pawn` are both strings.

Comment: Could you give an example of the strings you're trying to compare?

Comment: I am trying to reference emptyspot[][] as emptyspot[2][1] which equals "  Pawn  " and pawn equals "  Pawn  ".  They both are the same thing.

Comment: Provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/). The values in the variables may not have the value you think it is.

Comment: Does `if (" Pawn " == " Pawn ")` work for you? Any chance that there are differences in spacing or capitalization?

Comment: What happens if you use the `match` function instead of `==` ?

Comment: You may not notice, but the first rule of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is **short**, that example is **too long**. Try extract the problem out of it. The first thing you may test is to print both strings out.

Comment: Have you considered properly formatting your code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, please, please indent code with four spaces so that the Markdown formatter will know it is code and do the right thing. You had used a blockquote marker (`> `) at each line, and worse, had allowed some editor to re-wrap the Lua code as if it were English text. I believe I fixed most of the damage that did, but I gave up trying to count characters in your function `chessBoard()`.

Comment: And that is one of the reasons why there are several calls above for finding a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Another reason is that in the process of eliminating the bits that are not the problem, you often are able to discover and see the problem more clearly, and may even answer your own question in the process of trying to reduce it to ask it out loud.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
input = io.read("*line") 
loc1 = string.sub(input, 1, 1) 
loc2 = string.sub(input, 2, 2)
```

You're reading the input in as strings but your `emptyspot` table uses numeric indices as keys. Try fixing it with:

```
loc2 = tonumber(string.sub(input, 2, 2))
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer from [greatwolf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20014636/68204) is certainly the source of your immediate problem.

It is not that Lua can't compare the strings, but that you had actually looked up a non-existent element of the 2D array you indexed, and were always comparing `nil` to `pawn` as a result.

That said, I have a few comments about the rest of the code, and the problems you are going to encounter soon.

First, if you find yourself copying and pasting code to build up a large regular structure, look for opportunities to use loops and functions to abstract out the common elements. The monster function `chessBoard` is a good example. Fundamentally, what it does is print out the board, which is an array of 64 squares, where each square is printed with a certain amount of ASCII-art. As you have it written, the code that indexes each square's current piece is deeply entangled with the code that is drawing the rest of the square. When you discover that you would rather use a different notation for the pieces (for instance, to distinguish White from Black which you don't do now), you will have a mess on your hands to edit that monolithic collection of `io.write` built up with carefully constructed strings.

Second, consider separating the model even further from the view. The model in this case is of a chessboard, which is an array of squares that may be empty or contain one of several kinds of piece of two colors. The view is how you draw the board to present it to the user. Your code here blends model and view because the pieces themselves are represented in the model by the actual string used to present them to the user in the view. Recognizing that this abstraction exists is important as you move forward to implementing algorithms more complex than merely displaying the board and moving pieces.

Third, long chains of `if` statements that repeat the same test with different constants are almost always easy to turn in to much more compact (and more efficient) expressions.

You write `if ((loc1 == "C") or (loc1 == "c")) then loc1=3 end` for each of A to H. This can be simplified two ways. First, fold the input case so you are testing for a single case of character, then use `string.find` to convert from letter to integer at once. So the whole block of 8 `if-then` statements could be written as

```
loc1 = ("abcdefgh"):find(loc1:lower())
```

which will either make loc1 be an integer from 1 to 8, or `nil` if that character is not in the range A to H.

Fourth, `io.write` can take multiple arguments, which will be output consecutively without any delimiters (unlike `print` which inserts tabs between arguments and a newline at the end). So those long expressions in `chessBoard()` can have all of the string concatenation replaced with simple commas. This is not only faster, but it prevents the creation of a great deal of garbage for the garbage collector to eventually handle which comes from all of the temporary strings needed to complete the expression.